# How can I close a websockethandle when it has an error

Tags: go, go-gin

```
func WsConnectionHandle(ctx *gin.Context){
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(ctx.Writer, ctx.Request, nil)
    if err != nil{
        config.Error.Println("connect err", err.Error())
        //config.Error.Fatalln("connect err")
        ctx.Abort() 
    }
    ...
```

when I use `ctx.Abort()` it still ran the code below, and if I use Fatalln, my main process will stop~

and this is my router

```
gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
route := gin.Default()
resource.User(route.Group("/api/user"))
resource.KingAngAngle(route.Group("/api/king-and-angle", resource.JWTAuth()))
resource.Blessing(route.Group("/api/blessing", resource.JWTAuth()))
route.GET("/ws", chat.WsConnectionHandle)
```

Comment: Use a `return` statement, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `ctx.Abort()` is a function call, nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't affect the flow/scope of the function in which it's called. If you don't want to execute anything after calling `ctx.Abort()`, then just `return` to exit the function:

```
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("some error: %+v", err)
    ctx.Abort()
    return // exit function
}
```